# c# UserControl base class inheritance

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, user-controls

I have a base class call PopupWindow which inherits from UserControl.  PopupWindow has no associated xaml page, its just a regular class which inherits from UserControl

I then have another UserControl which inherits from PopupWindow.  Now this is a proper user control in that is has an associated xaml page.

I have changed the root xaml tag to be PopupWindow like this

```
<local:PopupWindow
  .....
</local:PopupWindow>
```

where local is the namespace in this PopupWindow exists.

But I keep getting an error that PopupWindow does not exist in the given namespace.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get this working as follows:

**Parent control:**

```
public class PopupWindow : UserControl
{
}
```

**Inheriting control:**

Code behind:

```
public partial class PopupWindowChild
{
    public PopupWindowChild()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Controls:PopupWindow x:Class="MyNamespace.Controls.PopupWindowChild"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls">
    <TextBlock Text="Blah" />
</Controls:PopupWindow>
```

Main view:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls">
    <Controls:PopupWindow />
</Window>
```

Your XAML won't recognise your control until the code is built.  Once built and run, I'm seeing "Blah" in my main view as expected.

Comment: Thats great you got it working.  What if PopupWindow uses generics, i.e public class PopupWindow<T> : UserControl ?

Comment: Great stuff, glad I was able to help.  Please make sure to mark the answer!  Have a look at [this](http://jamescrisp.org/2008/05/26/wpf-control-inheritance-with-generics/) for more information on WPF controls with generics.

Comment: The code behind for PopupWindowChild does not itself show any inheritance - I assume that the autogenerated code from the XAML would contain this instead? (in its partial class declaration)?